# scroll down in xpdf pressing only once on the middle scroll button of the mouse

Tags: mouse, pdf, mouse-scroll

I am very beginner in Linux.

I have 3 questions please.
I will number them, so it will be easier for you to answer.

1. Tell me please is there any way to scroll down in a pdf file with xpdf only pressing once on the middle scroll button of the mouse.

In that way the cursor will transform in a row and can move the page to up/down/left/right only by moving the mouse without pressing anything else.

If this would help someone please... http://www.conrad.id.au/2011/08/middle-mouse-button-scrolling-on-linux.html

This is possible for example in Portable Sumatra PDF for linux.

2. Do you know please any other light pdf viewer which can do the demand from question 1?
3. Does someone know any way to install Sumatra PDF in Linux?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Hi again,  Please tell me, if someone knows how could I send a message to  xpdf stuff, maybe they can add this option to the next version please? In my opinion it could be useful to many people, hopefully. Thank you very much.